# Hide the cursor not the mouse pointer

Tags: c#, winforms, button, events, textbox

I have a TextBox and a button: button_InputComplete. When I finished inputting the data in the TextBox I press the button and the button_Click event handler is invoked.
While the button_Click event handler is executing there remains a cursor in the TextBox at the end of the input data (a vertical blinking line).
I would like to hide this cursor. I do not mean the mouse pointer but the cursor in the TextBox (the vertical blinking line). I also need to be able to restore it.
The Cursor.Hide() statement hides the mouse pointer.
I tried to move the focus away from the TextBox with the statement: this.Select(); but the cursor remained in the TextBox.
I also tried the statement: control.Select(); where control is an instance of another control located on the form (not the TextBox), but neither this worked (the cursor remained in the TextBox).
Any help with an idea would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [HideCaret function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-hidecaret) -- Maybe you just want to set the [ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly) property.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use native code within my C# program. I would appreciate a code example not only the method itself but also the calling code and the using clauses. The ReadOnly mode for the TextBox is not a good solution for me because the user must be able to edit the input he just typed.

Comment: Then `HideCaret()` won't do, since you have to call `ShowCaret()` after, using the same handle. Just select the next Control that can receive focus (your Form cannot), e.g. `SelectNextControl([Your TextBox], true, true, true, true);`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much indeed! That works. I did not know about the statement SelectNextControl. Pity that you did not post an answer. Then I could have selected it as the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because your scenario is *undefined* in my view. E.g., *While the `button_Click` event handler is executing there remains a cursor in the TextBox*;  that doesn't happen: when you click a Button, it receives the Focus, hence a TextBox previously focused doesn't show the caret anymore, even if the code in Button.Click handler is blocking (because the Focus has already moved). So I just gave you something you can try. -- You can post an answer yourself, explaining what is going on there. Or describe better what's actually happening and I can suggest how to solve it.

Comment: @Jimi what is actually happening I already described. Allas! I do not know how to explain. I have 3 TextBoxes in a row and when the information is inputted in all three of them, the button gets enabled. When I click it, its event handler is executing but the Caret remains in the first! TextBox not in the TextBox where the last information was written. Aniway, the SelectNextControl statement makes the Caret disaperar, so thank you again.